# Web App not showing up in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I've created an on-premises development environment for apps for SharePoint.

I've jumped throught the myrriad of hoops in order to get all of this working and I can build and deploy the apps to SharePoint but when I come to add an instance of the Web App to a page it does not appear in the list.

This is what I mean:

**The apps seem to be deployed to SharePoint because it appears in the Apps in Testing library:**

[image: Developer's site Home Page]

**But when I edit the home page the app parts are not listed: -**

[image: Insert App Part]

**This is in contrast to the blurb in the microsoft sample which shows the app part listed-**

[image: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179921.aspx]

Am I missing a configuration step?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The App Parts are in the list.

They are the ones which say ClientWebPart Title, and ClientWebPart1 Title.

This is because when the App Part is created by Visual Studio it does not change the Web Part to the same name as the Project Name.

This has to be changed manually by editing the Elements.xml file: -

[image: Elements.xml]

Change the Name and Title and the app part will appear in the list as you expect: -

[image]